# Specifying an array with a specific number of copies of two elements

Tags: list-manipulation

To specify an array of length `L` in Mathematica, where each entry is `someElement`, I'm accustomed to writing:

```
exArray=Array[someElement &, L];
```

However, let's say that I want to (quickly) generate an array of length `L` where there are `n` copies of `elementOne` and `L- n` copies of `elementTwo`.  Maybe `elementOne` is the string character `A` and `elementTwo` is the string character `B`.  I'd like to be able to position the two elements in two different ways: (1) where the first `n` elements are all `elementOne` and the remaining elements are all `elementTwo`, and (2) where we have a uniform random sample from the set of all possible arrays where there are `n` copies of `elementOne` and `L - n` copies of `elementTwo`.

Are there simple "one-liners" to do (1) + (2)?

Comment: `ConstantArray` with `Join` for (1) and `RandomSample` for (2)?

Comment: @rm-rf What's the difference between using ConstantArray and Array?

Comment: Not much, really. `Array` is more flexible, but in this context, what you have and `ConstantArray` give the same result. You might find the 3rd argument of `ConstantArray` useful if you're initializing sparse arrays. I generally like to write code that "reads well", so if the intent of the line is to generate a constant array, I'll go with `ConstantArray`.

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks for your comment!

Comment: ConstantArray yields a packed array. Array doesn't AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For requirement (1):

```
Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ {{"A", 5}, {"B", 3}}
```

> ```
> {"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"}
> ```

Then for requirement (2):

```
RandomSample[%]
```

> ```
> {"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A"}
> ```

Or as a "one-liner:"

```
Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ {{"A", 5}, {"B", 3}} // RandomSample
```

Or as a function:

```
f[a_, b_, L_Integer, n_Integer] /; L >= n :=
  Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ {{a, n}, {b, L - n}}
```

Now:

```
f["A", "B", 7, 2] // RandomSample
```

> ```
> {"B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B"}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Extended comment about `ConstantArray` vs `Array`:

```
a = ConstantArray[0, 10000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.066234, Null} *)

MaxMemoryUsed[]
MemoryInUse[]
(* 102399424 *)
(* 102175120 *)

a =.;
a = Array[0 &, 10000000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.989285, Null} *)

MaxMemoryUsed[]
MemoryInUse[]
(* 342186712 *)
(* 102188984 *)
```

`ConstantArray` is faster and more memory efficient for long numerical arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`MapApply` and `Splice` came with V 13.1 and

```
RandomSample @ MapApply[Splice @* Table] @ {{"A", 5}, {"B", 3}}
```

{"A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A"}