# make a list based on two other lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
list1={4,6}
list2={1,2}
```

and I now want a function f that produces

```
f[list1_,list2_]:={1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2}
```

so 4 times the 1 and 6 times the 2.
f should be generic so that

```
3list1={2,3,7}; 3list2={1,2,3}
```

yields

```
res={1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3}
```

If you know several ways to do this please provide the fastest one. thanks a lot.

Comment: Table[list2[[#]], {list1[[#]]}] & /@ Range@Length@list1 // Flatten

Comment: `Flatten @ MapThread[ ConstantArray[ #2 , #1 ] &, { list1 , list2 } ]`

Comment: `Flatten@MapThread[ConstantArray[##] &, {list2, list1}]`

Comment: Related: [(40724)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40724) and related Stack Overflow question: [(763915)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/763915)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - related or not - how would you write this ?

Comment: @eldo I would write exactly what kguler did: `Inner[ConstantArray, #2, #1, Join] &`

Answer (score 4):

```
f[list1_, list2_] := Inner[Table[#2, {#1}] &, list1, list2, Join];
```

Comment: this is very clear and understandable, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = {4, 6}
list2 = {1, 2}

ClearAll[f];
f = Join @@ MapThread[Table, {#2, List /@ #1}] &

f[list1, list2]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} *)

f[{2, 3, 7}, {1, 2, 3}]
(* {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3} *)
```

or

```
h = Join @@ (Table @@@ Transpose[{#2, List /@ #1}]) &
h[{2, 3, 7}, {1, 2, 3}]
(* {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3} *)
```

or

```
g = Join @@ (ConstantArray @@@ Transpose[{#2, #1}])&

g2 = Inner[ConstantArray, #2, #1, Join] &
```

**Timings:**

```
bh = Inner[Table[#2, {#1}] &, #1, #2, Join] &; (* BobHanlon *)

{listA, listB} = RandomInteger[100, {2, 100000}];
(rs1 = bh[listA, listB]); // Timing
(* {0.265625, Null} *)
(rs2 = g[listA, listB]); // Timing
(* {0.062500, Null} *)
(rs3 = g2[listA, listB]); // Timing
(* {0.078125, Null} *)
(rs4 = h[listA, listB]); // Timing
(* {0.296875, Null} *)
(rs5 = f[listA, listB]); // Timing
(* {0.296875, Null} *)
rs1 == rs2 == rs3 == rs4 == rs5
(* True *)
```

Comment: your solution is the fastest so far.

Comment: @eldo As usual I'm the slowest so far :)

Comment: With two 10^6 - Integer-Lists, MM 9.01 and 4 cores: Bob Hanlon -> 1.34, kguler -> 1.53, mfvonh -> 2.07, eldo -> 3.15 (up to 3 repetitions).

Comment: @kguler - why is "g" so much faster than "f" given the fact that both are kguler-offsprings :)

Comment: @eldo, it is because i could not get `g` working properly first time I tried and `f` worked right away :) I cannot locate the source on this site right now, but `Join@@..` is usually faster than `Flatten` and `ConstantArray` is also faster than alternatives like `Table` and `Array`.