# How to imitate list comprehensions for constant arrays?

Tags: syntax, list-manipulation, custom-notation

In Python, `['a'] * 10` generates

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

and `10 * [1,2]` gives

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

How can I replicate an approximation of this infix syntax?

**Update:** I'm trying to use InfixNotation from Needs["Notation`"] but no luck so far.

Comment: `ConstantArray` ?

Comment: The consision of the infix notation is what I'm after.

Comment: `Star[{a_},n_Integer]:= ConstantArray[a,n]`

Comment: although I would use a more distinct symbol personally

Comment: Related: [(40724)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40724/121), [(73174)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73174/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Unevaluated@Sequence[1, 2]~ConstantArray~10
```

$\ $ `{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}`

Or using `Notation`

```
<< Notation`

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"[", "const_", "]"}], "\[Star]", 
     "reps_"}]] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Unevaluated", "@", 
RowBox[{"Sequence", "[", "const_", "]"}]}], "~", "ConstantArray", "~",
      "reps_"}]]]
```

Now

```
[1, 2]\[Star]10
```

$\ $ `{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}`

Which displays as
[image: ScreenSnipped]

---

Using `InfixNotation`

```
pythonStar[const_List, reps_Integer] := ConstantArray[Unevaluated[Sequence @@ const], reps]

InfixNotation[ParsedBoxWrapper["\[Star]"], pythonStar]
```

Now

```
{1, 2}\[Star]10
```

$\ $ `{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}`

Answer (score 14):

The Notation package is not necessary to use an infix form of `\[Star]` as that is handled automatically.  Also I recommend `PadRight` for constructing your expression (reference [Generating a matrix using sublists A and B n times](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1633/121)).

```
SetAttributes[Star, HoldFirst]

Star[a_List, n_Integer] := PadRight[a, n*Length@a, a]

{1, 2}⋆5    (*  ⋆ is \[Star]  *)
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}
> ```

`\[Star]` may be entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`star`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

---

#### Performance

Let me demonstrate why I recommend `PadRight` instead of `Sequence` in `ConstantArray`:

```
foo = Range[100];
n = 250000;

ConstantArray[Unevaluated[Sequence @@ foo], n] // ByteCount // RepeatedTiming
PadRight[foo, Length[foo]*n, foo]              // ByteCount // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {1.18, 600000080}
>
> {0.0470, 200000144}
> ```

So here `PadRight` is 25 times faster, and because the output is a packed array it uses one third the memory.

One may be tempted to use `"Periodic"` padding but unfortunately it is slower:

```
PadRight[foo, Length[foo]*n, "Periodic"] // ByteCount // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.4805, 200000144}
> ```

Still a packed array and faster than `Sequence` however!

Comment: One could use `"Periodic"` for the padding.

Comment: @Karsten `PadRight` is much faster than `ConstantArray` when used well.  `"Periodic"` looks nice but slows down `PadRight`, but still not so much as to be as slow as `ConstantArray`.  I'll add timings to this post.

Comment: @Karsten Please see the update.  If your results do not agree please tell me which version you are using.

Answer (score 10):

Brief? How about this. Define:

```
c = ConstantArray;
```

Now you can get what you want using the infix notation:

```
"a"~c~7
```

and

```
10~c~7
```

With lists

```
{1, 2}~c~7
```

you'll need to Flatten.

Answer (score 3):

Define `p` for `python`:

```
a_ ~ p ~ b_List := Table[Splice[b], a]
a_ ~ p ~ b_ := Table[b, a]

10~p~{1, 2}
```

{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}

```
5~p~"a"
```

{"a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}

Answer (score 3):

[`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)

```
g /: g[x__] * y_ :=
    ConstantArray[{x}, y] // Flatten

g /: y_ * g[x__] :=
    ConstantArray[{x}, y] // Flatten

g[1, 2] * 5

5 * g[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an infix operator named [Star](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/Star.html) which can be entered as `esc` star `esc` and looks exactly like the multiplication sign:

```
a_\[Star]b_List := Table[Splice[b], a]
a_\[Star]b_ := Table[b, a]

?Star
```

[image]

```
10 * {1, 2}
```

{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2}

```
5 * "a"
```

{"a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}

Again: write the above as: 5 `esc` star `esc` "a"

**Documentation**

[Language Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SymbolicNotationalForms.html)

[Operators without built-in meanings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TextualInputAndOutput.html#41)

Answer (score 1):

Other possibilities

```
SubstitutionSystem[{1->1,2->2},{1,2},9] // Flatten

SubstitutionSystem[{1->2,2->1},1,19] // Flatten

(* 
   {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2}
   {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2}
*)
```

and

```
NestList[#&,{1,2},9]//Flatten

(* {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2} *)
```